# Is it possible to define custom JAXB marshalling adapter for a member of collection?

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I have a main class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Foo {
  @XmlAnyElement
  public Collection<Object> items;
}
```

Now I'm adding a new element to this `items` collection, in runtime:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ItemAdapter.class)
public class Item {
}
```

And I'm expecting a call to `marshal(Item)` in ItemAdapter during marshalling of `Foo`:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Item> {
  @Override
  public String marshal(final Item item) {
    return "hello";
  }
}
```

But this call is not happening, instead I'm getting this exception:

```
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "Item" as 
an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

What am I doing wrong? Keep in mind that `Foo.items` may contain elements of other types, not only `Item`.

Comment: add @XmlRootElement to Item class :D